# Three.js CyclinderGeometry - modifying verts in one, effects the other

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I have a game with tiles and fog of war on top of those tiles. I use CylinderGeometry to create hex tiles. Then i create another CylinderGeometry and place it above the hex tile, that new tile acts as a fog of war. For a fog tile, I wanted to randomize verts a bit, so that it looks less uniform. But by doing so, I encountered an issue where my original tile also gets randomized. I don't really understand how that happens. I tried creating fog tile first too, but still the ground tile is also randomized.

Here is my code:

```
class Tile extends THREE.Object3D 
{
    constructor ( radius, gridX, gridY, fogMaterial ) 
    {
        super();

        this.gridX = gridX;
        this.gridY = gridY;

        this.gameEntityType = 'Tile';

        let height = .25;
        let geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(radius * .8, radius * .8, height, 6);
        let tileColor = this.randomColor();

        let material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial( { color: tileColor, shininess: 10 } );
        material.flatShading = true;
        let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.add( mesh );

        const fogGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(radius * .8, radius * .8, height * 10, 7);
        const per = 0.25;
        const perY = 2.5;
        fogGeometry.vertices.forEach(v => 
        {
            if ( (v.x - radius) < 0.3 && (v.z - radius) < 0.3 )
            {
                v.x += map1(Math.random(), 0, 1, -per, per);
                v.y += map1(Math.random(), 0, 1, 0, perY);
                v.z += map1(Math.random(), 0, 1, -per, per);
            }
        });
        const fogMesh = new THREE.Mesh( fogGeometry, fogMaterial );
        this.add( fogMesh );

        fogMesh.position.y = 3;

        return this;
    }
}
```

Any clues why this would happen? Does THREE cache some things underneath?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcL7o8ua/2/)

Edit: I dumped the vert positions of the tile before and after fog gets generated and they match. I read that Geometry gets converted to the BufferGeometry at some point, could that cause this?

Comment: Can you please try to demonstrate the issue with this live example https://jsfiddle.net/08ups9qL/1/? I've adapted your code but I'm not able to reproduce the reported problem.

Comment: @Mugen87 i updated the fiddle. You can see the effect when you comment in/out line 36 in the html window. (https://jsfiddle.net/bcL7o8ua/) Edit: I thought maybe it was shadow or something, but if i rotate and look under, you can still see separation between tiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the problematic bit in your code is this line:

```
let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(hex);
```

The displacement of vertices leads to a bigger AABB. Since you use the AABB to position your tiles, it seems the entire object is shifted in a wrong way.

`three.js R112`

Comment: ooooooooooh. that's it. lol. That never crossed my mind at all. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, that was actually hard to debug XD